# JS получение данных с input и отправка на почту

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Добрый день. Реализовываю отправку данных с input формы на почту.

Я все настроил, отлично работает, почту отправляет, но только если на странице одна форма. Если же я хочу сделать 2 формы, то при нажатии на кнопку "отправить" второй формы на почту приходит пустое сообщение, это связано с тем, что в `mail.php` указаны данные по отправке только для формы 1.

Я хочу сделать для каждой формы свой файл с настройками `mail1.php` и `mail2.php`

Нужно сделать так, что бы js определял с какой формы `<form id="oneForm">` или `<form id="twoForm">` приходит запрос. Если с формы `<form id="oneForm">` то передавал данные в `mail1.php` если же с `<form id="twoForm">` то в `mail2.php`

Привожу ниже код моего js.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("form").submit(function () {
    // Получение ID формы
    var formID = $(this).attr('id');
    // Добавление решётки к имени ID
    var formNm = $('#' + formID);
    var message = $(formNm).find(".msgs"); // Ищес класс .msgs в текущей форме  и записываем в переменную
    var formTitle = $(formNm).find(".formTitle"); // Ищес класс .formtitle в текущей форме и записываем в переменную
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'sendmail/mail.php',
        data: formNm.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
          // Вывод сообщения об успешной отправке
          message.html(data);
          formTitle.css("display","none");
          setTimeout(function(){
            //$(formNm).css("display","block");
            $('.formTitle').css("display","block");
            $('.msgs').html('');
            $('input').not(':input[type=submit], :input[type=hidden]').val('');
          }, 3000);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, text, error) {
            // Вывод сообщения об ошибке отправки
            message.html(error);
            formTitle.css("display","none");
            // $(formNm).css("display","none");
            setTimeout(function(){
              //$(formNm).css("display","block");
              $('.formTitle').css("display","block");
              $('.msgs').html('');
              $('input').not(':input[type=submit], :input[type=hidden]').val('');
            }, 3000);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
//для стилей формы
  var $input = $('.form-fieldset > input');
  $input.blur(function (e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('filled', !!$(this).val());
  });
});
```

В `mail.php` идет непосредственный сбор данных с инпутов и отправка почты.

Буду очень благодарен любой помощи!

Comment: мне кажется самым простым решением в данной ситуации является вынесение вашего кода в функцию, аргументами который будут имя формы и путь к файлу обработчика

Answer (score 1):

Добавить formID к файлу php

url: 'sendmail/mail' + formID + '.php'

Назовём formID = 'FormOne';
соответственно файл необходимо назвать mailFormOne.php

Comment: Спасибо! работает но не до конца. formID во второй форме отдает правильное название `twoform` а в первой форме отдает `undefined` почему-то

Comment: значит в первой форме нет идентификатора ID, по всей видимости

Comment: Проблема была в том, что у меня был незакрытый <form> чуть выше, я его не заметил по началу. Теперь все работает, спасибо!